# Smooth selection behaviour in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Below is the sandbox link -

https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-component-bkjr1?file=/src/App.js

I want to have a smooth behaviour on the background when user selects any of the option from the tab. The background changes abruptly as of now. I want to have similar behaviour as of tabs in material-ui as the indicator moves from one selected option to the other.

Edit-1: I want to implement the slide behaviour on the background.

Edit-2: [image: Sonmething similar to this]

Comment: What you are asking for is obtained by not using the background of the static positioned elements of your menu. Instead, you create an extra element, positioned absolute, relative to the parent and rendered below the menu items. You animate this elements' position and size based on currently active item, each time you change the active element. Have a decent go at coding it and, should you run into trouble, include what you've tried in the question body and mark it for re-opening.

Comment: Just to check - you want the purple background to slide from  its current position to its new position on a click - is that correct?

Comment: @tao thanks for the approach. Will try that.

Comment: @AHaworth yes, I wanted to have that slide effect.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, in Vue 3, which is pretty similar to React. Should give you an idea about what you need to do. If anything is not clear, please ask.

```js
const { createApp, reactive, onMounted, watch, toRefs } = Vue;

createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      items: ['All Posts', 'Public', 'Private'],
      activeIndex: 0,
      menuRef: null,
      menuItemRefs: [],
      floaterStyle: {}
    });
    const updateFloater = () => {
      const e = state.menuItemRefs[state.activeIndex]?.getBoundingClientRect();
      const m = state.menuRef?.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (e && m) {
        state.floaterStyle = {
          inset: `${
            e.top - m.top}px ${
            m.right - e.right}px ${
            m.bottom - e.bottom}px ${
            e.left - m.left}px`
        }
      }
    };
    onMounted(updateFloater);
    watch(() => state.activeIndex, updateFloater);
    return toRefs(state);
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.menu {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.menu div:not(.floater) {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .1s linear;
}
.menu .floater {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: inset .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.menu .active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="menu" ref="menuRef">
    <div class="floater" :style="floaterStyle"></div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in items" v-text="item"
         :class="{active: key === activeIndex}"
         :ref="el => el ? menuItemRefs.push(el): void 0"
         @click="activeIndex = key"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** [Same thing](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-component-forked-eobvq?file=/src/App.js), in React.
I strongly advise you to do the *"translation"* to React yourself. You'll learn more and you'll end up understanding what's going on in DOM, under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Tao, but I couldn't understand it. Can you just give a highlight of your approach?

Comment: I'm render the menu items. I have an extra item (`.floater`) which is positioned absolute, behind the menu items. The floater gets its style computed from the differences between menu's `getBoundingClientRect` and the selected item's `getBoundingClientRect`. And it's updated every time the currently selected one changes. That's it.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks for the approach. :)